# Jquery Dynamic append issue in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-table, append

I have a table with tbody

```
<tbody id="box"> </tbody>
```

i append element dynamically in this tbody using jquery.

```
$("#loading").show();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "showlistForm",
    async: true,
    data: {
        "next": selectId,
        "limit": limit,
        "skuValue": map,
        "pageNo": pageNo,
    },
    success: function(response) {
        if(response.status == null) {
            $("#box").empty();
            var a = response.result;
            $.each(a, function(i, e) {
                var rowData = '';
                rowData = '<td ><input type="text" id="stockistId' + i + '" value="' + (i + 1) + '" isVal="' + e.stockistId + '"  style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px solid;min-width:10px;   max-width:20px;font-size: 12px;" /></td>' + '<td ><input type="text"  value="' + e.salesStockistName + '"  style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px solid;font-size: 12px;width:100%;" /></td>' + '<td ><input type="text"  value="' + e.salesStockistCode + '"  style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px solid;font-size: 12px;width:100%;" /></td>' + '<td class="box" id="stockID_' + i + '" ></td>' + '<td><input type="text" readonly  id="sfaStockistCode' + i + '" value="' + e.sfaStockistCode + '" class="inputSFACode"/></td>' + '<td ><input type="text" id="sfaStockistId' + i + '" readonly value="' + e.sfaStockistId + '" class="inputSFAId" /></td>';
                $('<tr></tr>').empty().append(rowData).appendTo('#box');
                $('#stockID_' + i).empty().append($($("#stockistId").html()).val(e.sfaStockistName).attr("id", 'stockistBoxId' + i)); // most time consuming operation  
            }); // end foreach
            $("#loading").hide();
        }
    }
})
```

When I have 10 or 25 rows my browser does not respond for 1 or 2 second and my `#loading` image is also not responding. What should I do?

I tried debugging this method. The most time consuming scheme is `for each` loop especially select box (`#stockID`), it is taking time to append elements.

Comment: You've got and extra set of `$()` in your most time consuming line. Why such way?

Comment: I call particular elements by jquery, i need that elements to perform operations.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tz5866td/1/ try to change code like this

Comment: by using `$($('element').html)` is super inefficient. Instead add a selector to the html u want to change and then select it to change ur ID and val.

Comment: i use  $("#stockistId").html() to for my an existing combo on html which i apend into every row and show selected value which is coming from database.

Comment: Thankx @user3819192 it's working but there is no change in response time.

Comment: Table is one of the heavy element in HTML to load and thus it takes time. 
I would suggest you to use DIV layout as loading would takes less time.